# AWS Redshift -- loading into a TIMESTAMP field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I'm using an AWS Kinesis Firehose to write a file to S3, which in turn loads into Redshift.  My table has a TIMESTAMP column on it:

```
create table TABLE_NAME
(
  ...
  COLUMN_NAME TIMESTAMP,
  ...
)
```

The Redshift COPY options in the Firehose give the format for the column:

```
DELIMITER '\t' GZIP DATEFORMAT AS 'YYYYMMDD' TIMEFORMAT AS 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' MAXERROR 1000
```

The data for COLUMN_NAME isn't always populated.  In that case, I set the data for the TIMESTAMP column to an empty string.  When this happens, I'm seeing Redshift load errors with error code 1206:

```
Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYYMMDDHH24MISS]
```

The interesting part is that my load is still succeeding.  The records with an empty string for this TIMESTAMP column still load to my Redshift table just fine, but I keep seeing these errors logged to the `stl_load_errors` table.

Is there a Redshift COPY option I should be setting to ignore these errors?  Is there a keyword I should set instead of a blank string in the data?

Comment: I believe you want to set to null, not an empty string.

Comment: I'm 95% certain that I tried writing the string "NULL" in that position to my stream before going with the empty string approach and that the load failed in a similar fashion.  I will try it again, though.

Comment: Don't write the string null, just write NULL. A String is a String, NULL is not a String. Also, by having NULL you can then use "where timestamp IS NULL" in your queries.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [ACCEPTANYDATE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-acceptanydate) param at your COPY command